# Android: Calling finish sometimes closes whole app

Tags: android, android-activity, application-shutdown

I have this strange behavior.
My app has several activities that the user can navigate back and forth between.
The app starts with a spash screen, and after a few seconds you get lunched into the main activity.
The splash screen is then removed from the stack.

If the user presses the "settings" button, a new activity is launched.
Every now and then when the user navigates back from the settings activity (or any other activity and wanting to return to the main activity), the app shuts down. No exceptions in the catlog what so ever (Yes, i removed filter to show all the lines from the entire system).
This happens on multiple different devices with different Android version, but not all the time.
I cannot find a pattern,

Sometimes it will work as expected for hours at end, then it will happen 2-3 times in a row.

I'm using a button on the bottom of the screen to navigate back and on the Click-event i simply call "finish()"
All activities is launched with "startActivity(*intent*)".

I have no idea how to continue to search for the reason when i cannot get any exceptions or warning at all. Do anyone have any idea to what's going on or how to continue my investigation?

Comment: _m using a button on the bottom of the screen to navigate back_ you created your own button to go to previous activity?

Comment: Yes, I'm following the design specified by the customer that hired me. I don't like it either hehe

Comment: Is it possibly you're launching the settings activity into a new task?  Are you setting any flags on the Intent?  Do any activities have weird `launchMode`s?

Comment: May i suggest you try to convince your customer of the default-android-way? Otherwise you will have a toolbar-back, a navigation-back and a custom-back, which all should do the same. And a bunch of upset users wondering why someone has to invent the wheel a second time...

Comment: Well, the toolbar is not present, so it's either the navigation buttons/gestures in Android or the "Back"-button I've added to the apps activities to go back. So far we've had no complains. This is for industrial use, so not a high user base.

Comment: Ryan: No flag, no launch modes. I'm sometimes passing some data with the intent, nothing else.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your manifest there.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes it will work as expected for hours at end, then it will happen 2-3 times in a row.

Android activity is very unpredictable entity. You see, OS can destroy activities in the background at its own discretion (for example, the lack of resources). So when you leave your activity you can't be shure, that it's will e alive, when you will come back on it. There are few ways to handle this problem.

I can advice you the current ones:

1. Back to the prev activity directly (open it, after your current activity finished)
2. (Advice/Best parctice) - ***Dont use activities so often!*** Please, use Fragments for your tabs screen. You should have only 1-3 activities in your application and N Fragments on them. Believe me, working with Fragment is much easier, productive and safe. And of course, Google recommend to use Fragments instead of Activities.

P.s. - read this https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/activities-or-fragments-a-little-sharing-c1ddc1041f79
It will help you to understand my answer fully.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't onDestroy be called if the system destroys the activity?
Maybe i should check if I have any memory leaks or such. This project has been on-going for 3 years and I'm not sure if the customer will want to put down the time and money to redo some of it with fragments at this point

Comment: Your description of how the cleaning up of activities in the background works isn't really accurate.  In particular, the activities remain on the back stack even if they're destroyed to reclaim memory.  So calling `finish()` would still reopen the previous activity: reopening it directly shouldn't be necessary.